# Select All checkbox is not working when I go to second page of a classic report in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have a page having a classic report in an Oracle APEX application. The first column of each row is a checkbox. Also, I have added a checkbox in the first column of headers row. The purpose of this checkbox is to provide Select-All, Unselect-All functionality so that when I select the header checkbox, the checkboxes in all rows get selected, and when I unselect it, the checkboxes get unselected. Here is JQuery code that I use on the "change" event of the header row's checkbox:

```
if ( $( '#selectunselectall' ).is(':checked') ) 
{
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',true)
}
else 
{
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',false)
}
```

The problem is that this functionality is working only for the first page, and only when it is first loaded. If I go to next page, this functionality no longer works, and also if I come back to first page, that functionality doesn't work even on first page.

Another problem is that when I select some individual checkboxes on first page, and then go to next page, and then come back first page, all the checboxes again come as unselected. It means the application doesn't remember user's selecttions when the user navigate out of page.

Can someone please help resolve these issues?

Comment: While others may have a more creative way to handle this, I can testify from personal experience that this is functioning as designed. The state of the checkbox is only maintained while the rows are visible on the page. You cannot set the state of rows on other pages that have not yet been loaded, and when you navigate to a new page, you lose the state of the previous page. In general you *must* perform any intended actions on those rows *before* navigating to the next page.

Comment: A further observation: the whole point of paging in the first place is *not* to load all of your data at once, which takes a lot more system resources and time. It forces you to deal with small subsets of your query results by design... If you want to perform check box operations of all your data at once, you're most likely going to have to return all of your data to a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

InteractiveReport - Columns - "Select" - Heading - "<"input type="checkbox" id="selectunselectall" onclick="$f_CheckFirstColumn(this)"">"

InteractiveReport - Attributes - Heqading - Fixed To - "None"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).